# Enforce requiredness with email validation rules?

Tags: validation, protocol-buffers, proto3

I'm using the `protoc-gen-validate` extensions to Protocol Buffer. I came across some other answers here but they didn't completely answer my question.

I'm trying to validate that the value passed into a field is a valid email, and that the field is populated. I tried the ignore_empty rule ( `[(validate.rules).string.email = {required: true}];`)  but am getting an error since its not available for `bool` fields.

Is there a way to do this?